# Using windows.arrange

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is supposed to be trivial but that's exactly the reason why its tough to figure out what is going wrong. I need to tile my excel windows dozens of times a day, so decided to record a macro to be a able to use a hotkey and avoid needing to press Alt+W+A Enter over and over.

```
Sub tile()
'
' tile Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlTiled
End Sub
```

However, when I try to run it, nothing happens. I have tried to use the hotkey and to run it directly. Is there anything about this code that should not be working properly?

Thanks.

Edit: The code works when no windows are minimized. However, when one or more windows are minimized the code will not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of windows within the same Excel application then:

```
Sub tile()
'
' tile Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    Application.Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlArrangeStyleTiled
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refer to the excel application. Try changing the line to `Excel.Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlTiled`

Comment: This worked, and I was able to use the ctrl+e hotkey. I'm not sure why the comment below says it won't work with this fix. Thanks.

Comment: Correction: This worked immediately one time but now no longer works again. I changed the hotkey to shit+e but it still won't work. Feels like some sort of weird excel thing.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I try to run it, nothing happens. I have tried to use the hotkey and to run it directly.

There is **nothing wrong** with your code. You don't have to Add `Excel` or `Application` to make it work as suggested in the other answers..

You can't assign <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>E</kbd> to it. It is reserved for `Flash Fill`. When you assign the key via `View Macros` select your macro and click on `Options`. There you can set the shortcut key. If you want to use <kbd>E</kbd>, then type <kbd>E</kbd> and you will see that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> has been assigned for it.

[image]